# Output File Default Location using MultiServer Agent Jobs

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent, ola-hallengren, multi-server-admin

I've used Ola's scripts for quite a while at several companies, and just started a new job at a company who has already implemented MultiServer Agent Jobs to execute backups, DBCC CheckDB and IndexOptimization. For whatever reason, the person who implemented the solution in mulitserver jobs removed the output file "string" (i.e. the path to the Log folder on the instance). When I copied that value from Ola's scripts after I deployed them on my local machine, it caused 2 of the full backup jobs to fail because it "couldn't find" the path. The machine that the failures occurred on has 2 instances, and so far as I know, the path to "Errorlog" is default and based on the installation selection of that default. Both instances are SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard, while all the rest of our instances are 2014 Enterprise (which really should make no difference...but who knows?).
I have removed the output file on the backup jobs so they will run successfully, but I'd really like to figure out the best way to implement this on all of our instances.
At the very least, I suppose I could remove the 2 instances that are barfing with the path and recreate them on the local instances...but that really kills the benefit of using MultiServer SQL Agent jobs.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer already asked about the new variable, releases in SQL Server 2014, "SQLLOGDIR", which makes perfect sense that my 3 instances of SQL Server 2008 R2 wouldn't know what to do with that. 
Here's the link:[SQLLOGDIR](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90ade7b7-2721-4ad1-9abb-eb09ee74aebe/variable-sqllogdir-not-found-error-while-running-ola-index-job?forum=sqldatabaseengine)